# separate files based on datetime in python

Tags: python

I have number of files in a folder. Each file contains a datetime stamp.

Example:
The file format is:

```
315251973836374016  Tried not to fall into the trap but the show scandal is amazing!    170061457   VonnaDiane  20130323    scandal NULL    NULL    NULL
```

I have to group the files based on this time stamp. i.e., in another folder i have to create files in the name of datetime 20130323, etc., and store  the values corresponding to the datetime

Note: The source file contain mixed datetime i.e., 20130323,20130324 etc.,

Hope i am clear.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I normally hate this but... What have you tried?

Comment: hey it sees your url is not correct!

Comment: @Schoolboy, please add: I will not make your homework :)

Comment: @RickyA Not actually I was not able to link it to whathaveyoutried.com, but the site said, *Such content is not allowed* :O !! Maybe I should...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to isolate the field that you want and then append to the relevant file, using your data as the file name

```
s = "315251973836374016  Tried not to fall into the trap but the show scandal is amazing!    170061457   VonnaDiane  20130323    scandal NULL    NULL    NULL"

parts = s.split("\t")
with open("path/to/output/to/%s" % parts[4], "a") as f:
    # parts[4] will be 20130323, assuming tab delimited
    f.write("%s\n" % s)
```

It's hard to be more helpful without more information. You may wish to verify that the data you're using is a valid date

Comment: Never use `str` as a variable name. It masks the Built in variable.